# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_resolver_dns_native_macos_aarch_64

Tags: java, macos, dns, netty, apple-m1

when I start the spring boot project in MacBook Pro with M1 chip, show error like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_resolver_dns_native_macos_aarch_64.jnilib
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.loadNativeLibrary(MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:92) ~[netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.<clinit>(MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:77) ~[netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$1.run(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:50) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.<clinit>(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:46) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
    ... 79 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_resolver_dns_native_macos_aarch_64 in java.library.path: [/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:376) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:146) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.loadNativeLibrary(MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:92) ~[netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.<clinit>(MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:77) ~[netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos-4.1.76.Final.jar:4.1.76.Final]
```

I have tried to add the dependencies:

```
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-resolver-dns-native-macos', version: '4.1.75.Final', classifier: 'osx-aarch_64'
```

did not fixed this problem. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem? I also tried to add dependencies like this:

```
implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-tcnative-boringssl-static', version: '2.0.52.Final'
```

did not work.

Answer (score 5):

While below dependency did resolve similar issue for me (I hope you did reload your gradle project to get the dependency change in action) :

```
implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-resolver-dns-native-macos', version: '4.1.75.Final', classifier: 'osx-aarch_64'
```

could you try with below dependency instead:

```
implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.75.Final'
```

Comment: Hi Preet, thanks. FYI only the dependency resolved this issue for me. I am on 4.1.82.Final with smallrye-mutiny-vertx. Here is my list of dependencies:





```
implementation "io.smallrye.reactive:mutiny:${smallryeVersion}"
    implementation "io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-core:${smallryeVertxBindings}"
    implementation group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.82.Final'

```